# Reverse for 'about_us' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['about_us/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\Z']

Tags: html, django, url

I am trying to view a blog post in the user module that is posted by the another user module. Here's my model:

```
class details(models.Model):
    about_us = models.TextField(max_length=255) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('admin_home')
```

views.py:

```
class about_us(DetailView):
    model = details
    template_name = 'usertemplates/aboutus.html'
```

I have added it to my designated template which is supposed to be shown as a different page.

```
{% extends 'usertemplates/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{{object_list.about_us}}
{% endblock content %}
```

also added path in urls.py:

```
path('about_us/<int:pk>', userviews.about_us.as_view(), name = 'about_us')
```

The error is given in my home template where I wanted the post as hyperlink.

```
Reverse for 'about_us' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['about_us/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\Z']
```

error at following line:

```
<a href="{% url 'about_us' post.pk %}" style="text-decoration:none;color:White;align-items:center;font-size:15px">About Us<span class="sr-only"> | </span></a>
```

Comment: How do you pass the context of `post` to the template? Have you tried `post.id` instead of `post.pk`?

Comment: In my database posts are designated with id. I tried post.id but the same problem persist.

Comment: if the problem is caused by the post primary key, how can I state just one post with CRUD functionality?

Comment: I repeat: How do you pass the context of `post` to the template? Check if `{{post}}` renders anything. Maybe you don't have any `post`?

Comment: I am bit confused of what you said. As I was following tutorial I thought of 'post' as a method to call out the primary key.  Can you please make a little more elaboration for a noob like me?

Comment: Is `about_us` depending on anything or just generic site with non-changable informations? If not, then `id` is not even needed and the view should not be `DetailView` but simple `TemplateView` and would not need any argument passed.

Answer (score -1):

have you created the 'app_name' in your application urls.py?

if you have created it you need to write in the tag 'a' element {% url 'app_name:about_us' post.pk %}

Comment: It does not matter. Setting appname is optional. Also, `url` function works, the problem is with the argument, which is `null`.